# Calling URL on Ajax callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, callback

When using the following code, the "POST" call in the "success" function of the callback doesn't seem to work.

The "success" function is called, and the alert "HERE" is shown, but the URL is not called.  A breakpoint in the "showData" servlet confirms it.

Am I missing something?

I'm trying to pass JSON data from one servlet to another.
In case it matters, I'm using JQuery and JQuery Mobile.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data/dataServlet"
    success: function (data) {
        success(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});



function success(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/data/showData",
        data: {
            items: data.theItems
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("HERE");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Were you able to see a record on Fiddler? The alert("HERE") could have also appeared on a 500 and still not hit your servlet.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I figured it out.  A silly mistake on my part with debugging.

**The above code is correct for anyone wondering how to call a second controller upon completion of the first using an Ajax callback.**